# Is there a way to get all the label attributes of columns in R

Tags: r, attributes

I have created a dataframe using the `read_survey()` command from the `qualtRics` package. The dataframe has variables (columns) that have a name (e.g. "Q1"), but they also have a label attribute (e.g. "What is your age?"). Is there a way to access all the labels and put them in a nice overview like a list or separate dataframe?

I have been able to access every label individually by using:

`attributes(df$Q1)`

Which gives the following outcome:

```
$label
                                                         Q1 
" What is your age?"
```

I know that I am supposed to give a reproducable dataframe to clarify my question, however I have no idea how to create these label attributes.

My desired outcome dataframe would look something like this:

```
Column 1           Column 2
Q1                 "What is your age?"
Q2                 "What is your name?"
etc                etc (i.e.The rest of the labels)
```

Or instead of a dataframe a list with all the labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

```
Q1 = runif(5)
Q2 = runif(5)

attributes(Q1)$label <- c("What is your age?")
attributes(Q2)$label <- c("What is your name?")


df <- data.frame(Q1, Q2)

purrr::map_df(df, ~attributes(.x)) %>%
  bind_cols(names = names(df), .)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, however I am not creating a dataframe with labels. I would like a list of all the labels already in there. I have edited my question so that hopefully it becomes more clear. The outcome would be a dataframe with two columns. one that has all the question names and one that has all the question labels.

Comment: Edited the answer. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because `attributes(df)$label` equals NULL. Probably because the label attribute is not part of the df, but exists within each individual variable in the df.

Comment: Updated the answer so that it uses attributes from columns.

Comment: Almost, I figured it out thanks to your help. Just some small tweeks. ```map_chr(df, ~attr(.x, "label")) %>%
  bind_cols(names = names(df), question = .)```